# Pascal's Triangle Java implementation

Tags: java, logic

I would like to findout the correct number of a Pascal's triangle by giving row and column number to a method.

I've found this piece of code:

```
public static int getPascalValue(int row, int column) {
    if ( column == 0 || column == row) {
        return 1;
    } 
    return getPascalValue(row - 1, column - 1) + getPascalValue(row - 1, column);
}

public static void main(String args[]) { 
    System.out.println("\r\n"+getPascalValue(3,2)); 
}
```

It seems correct to me but gives the wrong number.

For example the main should result number 2 but it gives me 3 since:

```
    1 
   1 1 
  1 2 1 
 1 3 3 1
```

I can't figure out the wrong recursion part, can anybody help me?

Thanks!

Comment: Maybe you're just confused as to whether it's zero-based or one-based?

Comment: Just change the `if` to `column == 1` in order to make the input 1-based.

Comment: As I'm sure you're aware, we are a question-and-answer site, not a coders-for-hire service. Please explain what you have tried so far and why it hasn't worked.  See: [Why is "Can someone help me?" not an actual question?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236) and [How to ask a good question when I'm not sure what I'm looking for?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/262527/how-to-ask-a-good-question-when-im-not-sure-what-im-looking-for)

Comment: @JoeC: this appears to be a "please help me debug found code" site.

Answer (score 2):

It's not about the recursion part or about the `getPascalValue()` method itself (per se): it's about the difference between 0-based indices and 1-based indices. The code is written to assume 0-based indices, i.e. the top of the triangle is at `(0,0)`; but you seem to expect 1-based indices in which case the top would be at `(1,1)`.

Simply correct for this when calling the `getPascalValue()` method from the outside, i.e. in `main()` do this:

```
int row = 3, column = 2;
System.out.println("\r\n"+getPascalValue(row - 1, column - 1));
```

Answer (score 1):

I answer myself:

```
public static int getPascalValue(int row, int column) {
    if(column == 0 )
        return 0;
    if (  column == row) {
        System.out.println("result di row: " + row +" column: "+ column + " = 1" );
        return 1;
    } 
    int result = getPascalValue(row - 1, column - 1) + getPascalValue(row - 1, column);
    System.out.println("result di row: " + row +" column: "+ column + " = "+ result);
    return result;//getPascalValue(row - 1, column - 1) + getPascalValue(row - 1, column);
}
```

the calculus was wrong, since I wanted to give an answer without manipulating the method.
The trick was the column case. Now works.